# Unable to loacte properites file in wicket

Tags: wicket

In my wicket application i have 3-4 different packages say pack1,pack2 and so on .
In pack1 i have different html and java classes. I am validating the null check by setRequired(true) and getting the message from properties file.I am naming my properties file as Send.properties ... as i have Send.html and Send.java in pack1.In properties file i am mentioning like this
formname.field.Required=The ${label} is missing
 I want to validate all the html fields which are present in different html pages of the same package (pack1)in one properties file say pack1.properties .So my question here is will one singe properties will be sufficient for one package where in all the validation will be taken care.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, wicket first looks for the property in the properties file associated to the page, and then in the properties asociated to the package (and after that in parents packages...).

But, as long as I know the package properties file is called `package.properties` (independently of the package name).

Comment: Here i have **com.abc.Login** package where  my login.html , .java and loginApplication.java along wiht **loginApplication.properties** are present.I have **com.abc.Registration** package where Registration.html and .java files are present . Now if i try with  loginApplication.properties it is not working for me and even i tried with com.abc.Registration.properties then it is not working for me. Can you let me know where i am doing the mistake

Comment: It seems your hierarchy is ok, so perhaps the 'formname.field.Required' is wrong. According to https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/form-validation-messages.html, in wicket 1.2 onwards you have to specify the property 'Required' in your 'loginApplication.properties'.